# How to access a local function globally

Tags: javascript

I want to call a local function from a global function and I get `foo is not defined` error. What is the proper and safe way to do it because I'll probably send a json object.

```
(function() {
  function foo(js) {
    // codes ....
    console.log(js);
  }
})();

function bar(result, validation) {
  if (validation) {
     // just call the function
    foo(result);
  }
}
```

Above approach meant to get a value from [Popup window](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp).

onclick event of a button in popup window:

```
// ...
btn.onclick = function(x) {
  try {
    window.opener.bar(x.value, variablePassed);
  } catch (err) {
    alert("an error occured.");
    console.log('err', err);
  }
  window.close();
  return false;
}
```

Above code block passes 2 values to `bar` function and in the `bar` function, I just wanted to pass the a value to `foo` function which is an important function that's why I wanted to make it local so it can't be accessed by client-side

Comment: Well, unless you return something from the wrapping immediately executed function or assign it to an externally visible variable (in which cases it won't be private anymore), you will lose all references to it and will not be able to call it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making JS local function globally accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769158/making-js-local-function-globally-accessible)

Comment: I would consider this bad practice since private functions are literally made to prevent what you're trying to do.. Maybe consider a different approach, or a refactor that wouldn't call for something like this.

Comment: @BrandonMiller Yes. I also think this is a bad approach. Maybe I should show why I need this approach. I'll edit the question soon

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 2):

You can't. That's most of the point of writing a private function in the first place.

If you want to call it from outside, you have to do *something* to expose the function to the wider scope. (i.e. *stop it being private*).

For example:

```
var foo = (function() {
  function foo(js) {
    // codes ....
    console.log(js);
  }

  return foo;
})();
```

Look up *the revealing module pattern* for an approach that deals with exposing multiple things from a closure like this.

Comment: Or the somewhat _common_ `window.foo = function`

Comment: @George — I really dislike that approach. It's explicitly global and specific to browser-based environments

Answer (score 0):

You can use "this" and design your scope function

```
(function() {
  this.foo = (js) => {
    // codes ....
    console.log(js);
  }
})();
```

Comment: In your code, `this` is the global object (i.e. `window`).

Comment: This does not work in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) (which you should be using because it saves you from some errors)

Comment: Why did you change from a function declaration to an arrow function? They behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

**Caution: The other answers are essentially making the function public.**

If you want to keep it private, you will have to define `bar` in a scope where `foo` is visible, and then make it available outside by assigning or returning it. For example like this:

```
const bar = (function() {
  function foo (js) {
    // codes ....
    console.log(js);
  }

  function bar (result, validation) {
    if (validation) {
      // just call the function
      foo(result);
    }
  }

  return bar;
})();
```

In this case `bar` will keep a reference to `foo`, and will be able to call it, but no other functions can access it. You can call it anywhere like this:

```
bar(result, validation); // This will run `foo` inside it's body.
```

*ps.: Be aware that this isn't the most secure method, because anyone can look at your client side source code and modify it. The best idea would probably be to do validation on the server.*

Comment: Probably OP has a reason for doing it this way that wasn't explained in the question. I mean, if there was no motivation for this why would someone even try to complicate it so much?